# Does SFDX add any way of automating the setup of business hours?

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, businesshours

It wasn't (and I assume still isn't?) possible to programmatically set up [business hours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm) via Apex code in unit tests:

- [Set Business Hours in Apex Test Code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33580/set-business-hours-in-apex-test-code)
- [Creating Holidays and Business Hours in Test Code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34474/creating-holidays-and-business-hours-in-test-code)

Is there any mechanism introduced in SFDX that helps with this problem?

(We have 29 tests that fail in a new, bare scratch org and some fail because an 8 hour business day is assumed.)

Comment: When you deploy code, are you including business hours as part of your package?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal No - didn't know that you could... I see that that metadata API came in at version 29.0 and this code was written against version 18.0. Any ideas without the business hours in the package?

Comment: Am not sure about API versioning, but if I am not wrong, you can deploy different components with different version numbers like different light components with different version number. So i think it should be fine. Though i never tried to guarantee.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Agreed we could add some business hours to the package as a solution and adjust/mix the API versions. But that means various ripples through e.g. our documentation so I'm wondering if there is an alternate solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can push/pull/deploy/retrieve [BusinessHoursSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_businesshourssettings.htm) as part of your source code repository. You'll find this file in /settings/BusinessHoursSettings.settings-meta.xml. If you're just getting started, you can retrieve it from an org (along with other settings) like this:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -u usernameoralias -m Settings
```

Comment: Sounds like what I am looking for. Will work on it now.

Answer (score 1):

As sfdcfox suggests, this stored as `settings/BusinessHours.settings-meta.xml` in an SFDX project does the trick for me (where I want 8 hours per weekday and zero hours on weekend days):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BusinessHoursSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <businessHours>
        <active>true</active>
        <default>true</default>
        <fridayEndTime>16:00:00.000Z</fridayEndTime>
        <fridayStartTime>08:00:00.000Z</fridayStartTime>
        <mondayEndTime>16:00:00.000Z</mondayEndTime>
        <mondayStartTime>08:00:00.000Z</mondayStartTime>
        <name>Default</name>
        <thursdayEndTime>16:00:00.000Z</thursdayEndTime>
        <thursdayStartTime>08:00:00.000Z</thursdayStartTime>
        <timeZoneId>America/Los_Angeles</timeZoneId>
        <tuesdayEndTime>16:00:00.000Z</tuesdayEndTime>
        <tuesdayStartTime>08:00:00.000Z</tuesdayStartTime>
        <wednesdayEndTime>16:00:00.000Z</wednesdayEndTime>
        <wednesdayStartTime>08:00:00.000Z</wednesdayStartTime>
    </businessHours>
</BusinessHoursSettings>
```