# How to Associate Holiday and Business Hours in Data Import

Tags: import, businesshours, holidays

Is there a way to insert/update Holidays and create the association to an existing Business Hour?  In the UI this is achieved by clicking into the Business Hour, clicking the "Add/Remove" button under Holidays and adding the Selected Holidays.  I have a lot of Holidays to add and I'd like to be able to create this relationship via a data import if possible.  I have to deploy to multiple sandboxes, so a solution via data import or code would be ideal.

Side note: I'm aware of the limitations on querying the junction between Holidays and Business Hours (see here: [Business Hours and Holiday Affiliation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33985/business-hours-and-holiday-affiliation/)), but I'm still hoping there might be a solution around the import.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official word from Salesforce Support: At this time, this is not a part of standard salesforce functionality.

So it looks like the Holiday/Business Hour association can only be accomplished manually on the UI.  Please go vote on this Idea if you're running into the same problem: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006n4CAAQ